Stem extensions and quotients of Schur covers
Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, and that $\Gamma$ is a central extension of $G$ by $A$, that is
$$ 1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow \Gamma \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1$$
with the image of $A$ contained in $Z(\Gamma)$. If $A$ is also contained in $[\Gamma, \Gamma]$ then this is a stem extension. For a stem extension, it is known that $A$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the Schur multiplier of $G$, but I have not been able to find a result in the literature relating $\Gamma$ to a Schur cover of $G$ unless $A$ is the full Schur multiplier. Here are some increasingly optimistic questions.

If $G$ is perfect and $\Gamma$ is a stem extension, is it true that $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a quotient of the Schur cover of $G$?

If $\Gamma$ is a stem extension, can we assume that $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a quotient of a Schur cover of $G$? (There might be multiple non-isomorphic Schur covers.)

If $\Gamma$ is a central extension, can we relate it the Schur cover of $G$ in any meaningful way?


The last question is what I'm really interested in. The type of answer I'd like (if such a thing is true) is a proof or reference showing that $\Gamma$ contains a subgroup which is non-split over $B = A \cap [\Gamma, \Gamma]$, that the non-split subgroup is isomorphic to a quotient of the Schur cover, and that $\Gamma/B$ splits. This seems overly optimistic, so I've asked the first two questions, to hopefully get some control over a more limited situation. Failing that, any references on equivalence of liftings of projective representations would be appreciated.

What do you mean by "$\Gamma/B$ splits"?

You seem to have "the" and "a" the wrong way round in Questions 1 and 2. You want "the Schur cover" in 1, because the cover is unique in that case, and "a Schur cover" in 2. Then the answers to 1 and 2 are both yes (although I would replace "can we assume that" by "is it true that").

I think what you are hoping for in Question 3 is probably false. The group $\Gamma={\rm GL}(2,5)$ has centre cyclic of order $4$ with $\Gamma/Z(\Gamma)= {\rm PGL}(2,5) \cong S_5$, and $\Gamma/\Gamma'$ is also cyclic of order $4$ with $\Gamma'= {\rm SL}(2,5)$ and $|Z(\Gamma) \cap \Gamma'|=2$. There is no subgroup with structure $2.S_5$, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Thank you @DerekHolt - I've made the edits you suggested. Do you have a reference for Q1 and Q2? If so, I'll be happy to accept this as an answer. And I agree that your counterexample shows that the general situation is more complicated than I had hoped.

@DaveBenson I should have expanded this: that $\Gamma$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\Gamma/B$ which is a complement to $B$.

@PadraigÓCatháin Then it's false, as Derek points out.

Sorry I am on holiday so you will have to wait for a reference but there are books that deal with the theory of central extensions.
